# JavaScript: Append child with style and loop

Tags: javascript, loops, styles, appendchild

I need to achieve the following:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
<li data-icon="false">
<!--loop content here-->
</li>
</ul>
```

using JavaScript. I think append child would do the trick. Can you tell me how to use appendchild to achieve that result? i tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).bind('deviceready', function() {
    //Phonegap ready
    onDeviceReady();
});


//var output = document.getElementById("output");
var _ul = document.createElement('ul');
var _li=  document.createElement('li');
_ul.setAttribute("data-role", "listview");
_li.setAttribute("data-icon", "false");

$.ajax({
    url: 'json_encoded_db.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item) { 

            _li.innerHTML = 
            '<a href="" id="'+item.id+'">'+
            '<img src="images/'+item.img+'">'+
            '</a>'; 

            _ul.appendChild(_li.cloneNode(true));
        }); 

    },
    error: function(){
       output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(_ul);
});
```

but it's not working, i mean, it's a list without any style and apparently does not get data-role properties. 
(obviously it works about getting data from database, i tested it).

Comment: What do you mean "it's a list without any style"? Nothing in the code shown does any styling. Are you saying the li elements *do* get created with the correct anchor and image contents, but without the `data-` attributes?

Comment: i have styled data-role="listview" and data-icon="false". Exactly, it does get created with the correct anchor and image contents but without the data- attributes.

Comment: I copied your code into a fiddle, and replaced the Ajax call with a timeout (because I couldn't get the Ajax to work in the fiddle), and the elements are being created correctly *with* the `data-` attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/uu35z9a3/

Answer (score 0):

move this code in your $.each() of your successCallback. So your $.each() will look like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) { 
    var _li=  document.createElement('li');
    _li.setAttribute("data-icon", "false");
    _li.innerHTML = 
        '<a href="" id="'+item.id+'">'+
        '<img src="images/'+item.img+'">'+
        '</a>'; 

        _ul.appendChild(_li);
});
```

Also get rid of cloning '_li'

Comment: could you post me the full code? because i keep getting the same.